# Custom inline Vf Page not Display the section

Tags: visualforce

Here is the screen shot.
[image]

AND THE CONTROLLER CODE.

```
public with sharing class inlineStandardAccount 

{

public Account a{get;set;}

public Account acc{get;set;}

 public inlineStandardAccount(ApexPages.standardController controller)

{

 system.debug('++++++++++++++'+controller);

 this.a=(Account)controller.getRecord();

 system.debug('++++++'+a);

system.debug('+++++++'+a.parentId);

acc=new account();

 acc=[select id,name,Phone,Fax,Rating,Ranking__c,Parent_Ranking__c  from account 

where id =:controller.getId() AND parentId !=null  limit 1];

if(null !=acc)

{

acc=[select id,name,Phone,Fax,Rating,Ranking__c,Parent_Ranking__c from account 

where id =:a.parentId limit 1];

}

system.debug('++++++++++'+acc);

}


public pageReference onsave()

{

update acc;

 system.debug('>>>>'+acc);

return null;

}

}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Can you describe it with more details?

Comment: Its Shows a visualforce error                                                         System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject 
Class.inlineStandardAccount.<init>: line 12, column 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of direct `Sobject` you should use **List of Sobject** (Account).
Change your query approach to a List as:

```
acc=new List<Account>();

acc=[select id,name,Phone,Fax,Rating,Ranking__c,Parent_Ranking__c  from account 
where id =:controller.getId() 
AND parentId !=null  
limit 1];

if(acc.size()==0)
{
   acc=[select id,name,Phone,Fax,Rating,Ranking__c,Parent_Ranking__c 
   from account 
   where id =:a.parentId limit 1];
}
```